# Android Studio error: cannot find symbol class SetContentView

Tags: android, class

I opened an existing project using Android Studio and when I want to run it in Android emulator, I face this error message:

[image]

Comment: Please paste the relevant java and xml so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Check if any Class named SetContentView exist in your source files

Comment: there is no class named SetContentView exist in my source files

Comment: @luke what is the class you are trying to access? What are you trying to do? Is it a class or are you trying to load a layout? You have to be more specific than  "I face this error message"

Comment: i'm not trying to access to anything , as i said i opened project i click sync button , everythings works well , but when i want to run it in android studio emulator , this error apears to me , i try to find SetContentView in my source code but i didn't find it , when i try create new SetContentView i don't understand what i will write on the class body ..........

Answer (score 1):

If it is to set the layout of the file, it is done in onCreate(in activity, fragments are different) and it isn't a class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
    super.onCreate(sis);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);
}
```

If the class SetContentView is used for something else, or a custom class, see if it exists in your source files.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I am trying to say its SetContentView class have and it can not find it in new  class. its his problem... Your answer does not match

Comment: If a class isn't found, it doesn't exist or the dependency it is in isn't imported.

Comment: If a class isn't found, the common way to go at it is to create or import it. If I don't know what @op is asking about, I can't answer it. Is he trying to set content view? Access a custom class designed to set the content view? A class not found isn't worth asking a question about

Comment: And I said if the class is used for something else or a custom class, see if it exists in the source. I answered both because I don't know what @op is trying to achieve

Comment: there is no class named SetContentView exist in my source files